# Google geocoder does not run. Cannot understand why?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, reverse-geocoding

Please note, the arguments 'origin' and 'destination' are both objects of type google.maps.LatLng.

I am trying to reverse-geocode these LatLng objects in order to obtain and return formatted addresses.

The function simply assigns 'undefined' to 'geocodedOrigin' and 'geocodedDestination'. I would like to know why the geocoder is not working?
Thanks.

```
    function geocodeLocations(origin, destination)
    {
         var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
         var geocodedOrigin;
         var geocodedDestination;
         var geocodedLocations;


         geocoder.geocode({'location': origin}, function(results, status) {

                if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                  if (results[1]) {

                    geocodedOrigin = results[1].formatted_address;
                  } 
                  else {                            
                    geocodedOrigin = 'No results found';
                  }
                } 
                else {                        
                  geocodedOrigin = 'Geocoder failed due to: ' + status;
                }
            });

          geocoder.geocode({'location': destination}, function(results, status) {

                if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                  if (results[1]) {

                    geocodedDestination = results[1].formatted_address;

                  } 
                  else {
                    geocodedDestination = 'No results found';
                  }
                } 
                else {
                  geocodedDestination = 'Geocoder failed due to: ' + status;
                }
          });

          geocodedLocations = [geocodedOrigin, geocodedDestination];

          return geocodedLocations;
    }
```

Comment: The geocoder is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

The geocoder is asynchronous.  It is working fine, the results come back in the callback *after* you have returned the array containing them.

You need to *use* the data returned by the geocoder inside the callback function where it is available.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36hqbg8x/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  geocodeLocations(
    new google.maps.LatLng(40.7127837, -74.0059413),
    new google.maps.LatLng(40.735657, -74.1723667));

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function geocodeLocations(origin, destination) {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var geocoder2 = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var geocodedOrigin;
  var geocodedDestination;
  var geocodedLocations;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();


  geocoder.geocode({
    'location': origin
  }, function(results, status) {

    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

      if (results[1]) {

        geocodedOrigin = results[1].formatted_address;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: results[1].geometry.location,
          map: map
        });
        bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        document.getElementById('origin').innerHTML = "origin=" + geocodedOrigin;
      } else {
        geocodedOrigin = 'No results found';
      }
    } else {
      geocodedOrigin = 'Geocoder failed due to: ' + status;
    }
  });

  geocoder2.geocode({
    'location': destination
  }, function(results, status) {

    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[1]) {

        geocodedDestination = results[1].formatted_address;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: results[1].geometry.location,
          map: map
        });
        bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        document.getElementById('destination').innerHTML = "destination=" + geocodedDestination;
      } else {
        geocodedDestination = 'No results found';
      }
    } else {
      geocodedDestination = 'Geocoder failed due to: ' + status;
    }
  });

}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="origin"></div>
<div id="destination"></div>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:750px; height:450px; border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks